# In SQL, can you specify a limit on a row condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, limit, conditional-statements, where-clause

For example, a table contains messages with a `is_read` field. Is there a way to use `LIMIT` to say "Give me all rows in this table, but I want to LIMIT the number of rows returned where `is_read` is `TRUE`?"

EDIT

Sorry, I may have not explained this well. I want all the rows where `is_read` is FALSE but be able to limit the rows returned where `is_read` is TRUE. I hope that makes more sense?

Answer (score 4):

You could union two queries together, one for each condition:

```
SELECT * FROM theTable WHERE is_read = 'false'

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM theTable WHERE is_read = 'true'
LIMIT 42
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `UNION` on two queries like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE is_read = 'false'
UNION
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE is_read='true' limit 5
```

Comment: Aha! I did not know you could do this.